# Call a function in a Yacc file from another c file

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I am new in Lex/Yacc programming. I have a question about how to call a function in Yacc file from another C file. Assume that I have following Lex/Yacc code:

**calc.l**

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"  
extern int yylval;
%}

%%
[0-9]+     { yylval=atoi(yytext); return NUMBER;} 
[ \t];                                           
\n         return 0;                              
.          return yytext[0];                      

%%
```

**calc.y**

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
%}
%token NAME NUMBER

%%
statement: NAME '=' expression
|      expression {printf("= %d\n",$1); printf("yylval= %d",yylval);}
;
expression: NUMBER '+' NUMBER {$$=$1+$3;}
|       NUMBER '-' NUMBER {$$=$1-$3;}
|       NUMBER 'x' NUMBER {$$=$1*$3;}
|       NUMBER '/' NUMBER
                {   if($3 == 0)
                        yyerror("Error, cannot divided by zero");
                    else
                        $$=$1/$3;
                }
|       NUMBER            {$$=$1;}
;
%%

void parse()
    {
    while(1) 
        {
        printf("Please enter numerical expression here: ");
        yyparse(); 
        }   
    }
```

And I created a main.c file so I could call the function void parse() in Yacc file like this:

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.c"
#include "lex.yy.c"

int main(int argc,char* argv[])
    {
    parse();
    }
```

The question is how I can call void parse() function in main.c and how to compile the main.c along with the Lex and Yacc file. I have tried with

1. yacc -d calc.y
2. lex calc.l
3. gcc -o main main.c

But it didn't work.

Comment: You should tell us why it didn't work and what message you got! I suggest you try: `gcc -o main calc.tab.y main.c`.

Comment: You should not `#include` `y.tab.c` or `lex.yy.c` into your main source file.  You could compile them all in the same `gcc` command (just add the source file names to the `gcc` command you already have), or you could compile them separately to object files (`gcc -c`) and later link the object files together.  That may or may not have anything to do with your problem, however.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian Tompsett and John Bollinger. It worked now

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling all of the files together as below:

gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c main.c -o main

And try running it as follows:

./main